# Помогите с условием в LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Застрял на элементарной задаче. Нужно при `IsShowNonPlayers == true`
добавлять в запрос условие отбора `where r.SourceDesc.Substring(0,1) == "P"`
либо если `IsShowNonPlayers == false` тогда `r.SourceDesc != ""`
сделал так но не работает(

````
                             where r.DateTime >= StartDateTime &&
                                   r.DateTime <= EndDateTime &&
                                   r.SkillType == "Physical" &&
                                   r.DamageIn != 0 &&
                                   r.AttackType != "ShowPowerDisplayName" &&
                                   IsShowNonPlayers ? r.SourceDesc.Substring(0,1) == "P" : r.SourceDesc != ""
                             select r.DamageIn).Sum();```
````

Comment: У оператора ?: внезапно приоритет ниже, чем у &&, в скобки своё выражение возьмите.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk Спасибо!